# How do we Update a Field on the Object using Salesforce Lightning Process Builder?

Tags: process-builder

In a usual normal Workflow Rule, we have Field Update action that could update the field on the Object record which is executing the Workflow Rule.

How do we update a single field on the Object record which is executing the Process Builder - Process? I can see there is ability to Update "Related List" records of the Object via Process Builder but not an option to update field on the object record itself.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you choose update record and have the list of related objects, you need to click on the object name to in the left hand column, which will then allow you to choose that objects fields. The following screenshots show the process on the case object:
[image: Action Type: Update Records]
[image: Case Selected]
[image: Case Field Selected]

Comment: Love it when its the first google result and provides a perfect answer. Thanks :)